# Setting up a Facebook Auth and whatnot

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface

I have been trying to set this up for a few days straight and I just cannot find any decent help anywhere and I am so tired of trying one tutorial after another to do something which shouldn't be too hard to accomplish!

All I have been trying to do is setup the application so I can request permissions to personalize what is shown to the user to add things such as 'Hello NAME' and whatnot to progress to posting to their wall and so on and so fourth...

I know my App ID and App Secret. One tutorial talks about an API Key, of which does not  display for me...

I am just so very confused what to do now and I have a ton of test files to delete so if you have anything of use, I would be ever so grateful!

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please let people know the language you code in.

Comment: Oops! I thought I mentioned this... I'm attempting to do this using PHP as I've heard it's the better way...

Answer (score 0):

Download the SDK, that you need to use. Here I am guessing you would be using the PHP SDK.

**CONFIG.PHP**

```
<?php

require_once ("fb/facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$redirecturi = "http://yoururl/";
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if (empty($user['id']))
{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' =>
            'YOUR PERMISSIONS HERE SEPERATED BY COMMA', 'redirect_uri' => $redirecturi));

    echo ("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
}
$userdata = $facebook->api('/me');
```

?>

To echo Hello Name,

Now you go with a new PHP file, index.php

```
<?php
include("config.php");
echo $userdata['name'];
?>
```

I know its bit of a spoonfeed, but yeah, It was so hard for me to start,so I would like others to get past that easily.

Would be useful for anyone else who is stuck at the start.

Comment: Thank you for what you have passed, however it does not seem to work. I first noticed on the code you told me to add to index.php, my Dreamweaver told me there was an error. Being fairly new, this is not yet obvious to me and I thought I would try anyway and I received this error message on Facebook:

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /homepages/0/d416312370/htdocs/SunlightGardenServices/SunLight/facebook/index.php on line 3

I also cannot see how opens up the Auth Dialog to request to access their data and whatnot as I can get some things to work for myself but as I cannot get the Auth Dialog to work, when my partner accesses the page he cannot see anything.

Comment: I have somewhat just found this to be of use, but yet again only to myself: [link](https://github.com/mahmudahsan/PHP-SDK-3.0---Graph-API-base-Facebook-Connect-Tutorial-Source)[link]

 I am also having the problems of this one, when you post to wall and whatnot, it is showing a graph and is not doing anything but the invite is working.

Comment: You should better spend more time in FB documentation and Googling up stuffs. I just paved a start for you. I think you have a nice start now.

Comment: I am grateful for your input, however what you have given me still does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Did you download the SDK and edited the config file which is then included in the index.php file? If Yes, it should do something. Should atleast give out an error. :) lol

Comment: I believe I edited everything correctly. I shall relook over things in the morning, make sure my Application settings are correct and whatnot aswell.